# Android Layout background color change

Tags: android, background

I've search quite a bit in google and extensively in this site also, if I missed the question that answer mine I'm sorry. But here it goes:

```
            public void onClick(View v){
            Button btt= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bttROnOff);
            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layScreen);
            if ((btt.getText()).toString().compareToIgnoreCase("Reading Mode OFF")==0) {
                ll.setBackgroundColor(R.color.paleYellow);
                WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
                lp.screenBrightness = originalBrightness;
                getWindow().setAttributes(lp); 
                btt.setText("Reading Mode ON");
            }
            else {
                ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
                lp.screenBrightness = 1;
                getWindow().setAttributes(lp); 
                btt.setText("Reading Mode OFF");
            }
            }
```

I have a button to change the background color to white and then to "paleYellow" which is defined in the strings.xml file. In my xml layout file, it starts with this color and when I press the button it changes to white. But if I press the button to return to the previous one, what I get is a black background. If I use instead:

```
ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.Yellow);
```

It works, but:

```
ll.setBackgroundColor(R.color.paleYellow);
```

Does not :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setBackgroundColor` takes an `int` that represent [a color in **sRGB**](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html), while `R.color.paleYellow` is an id of color, but not in the same representation. to use it, you should call [`setBackgroundResource(R.color.paleYellow)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29)

Comment: Thanks a lot ... need to pay more attention :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like...

```
Resources myRes = getResources();
int colorPaleYellow = myRes.getColor(R.color.paleYellow);
setBackgroundColor(colorPaleYellow);
```

or maybe something like...

```
setBackgroundcolor(this.getColor(R.color.paleYellow));
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do it:

```
ll.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.paleYellow));
```